# One liner ssh different enviroment variables than normal ssh

Tags: ssh

I am using AWS Beanstalk, in case it may be relevant to the question.

The issue that I have is that when I do from my local terminal:

`ssh mozart-api printenv`

I missing most of the enviroment variables, instead if I do:

`ssh mozart-api`

..wait to open..

`printenv`

I get all enviroment varibles as I was expecting.

At first I thought it could be an ssh configuration in server but can't find anything strange.

if I do:

`ssh mozart-api "export hello=123 && echo $hello"`

then it outputs 123, which means that variables can be set and queried, however I just cannot get the existing variables from the server.

This is causing an issue because I am preparing a script that will run a command in ssh on this server, but because the variables are not loaded the project fails to open the database.

I tried reimporting them in one liner:

`ssh mozart-api "sudo chmod +777 /etc/profile.d/sh.local && (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'keys[] as \$k | \"echo export \(\$k)=\(.[\$k])\"') > /etc/profile.d/sh.local && printenv"`

But still can't see the new added variables.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh mozart-api` executes a login shell, which probably sources one or more files that define your environment variables.

`ssh mozart-api printenv` executes `printenv` *instead* of a login shell, so the only variables you see are the ones you inherit from the parent process, not any of the variables defined in your shell configuration files.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that there _is_ a shell involved in interpreting the string passed as a command line -- though with the bottom line being that it's noninteractive and not a login shell, the conclusion holds.

Comment: is there a way to invoke this login shell within the one liner?